# Given a set of match results, how can I get all teams with at most 10 losses in O(n) time?

Tags: algorithm, performance, pseudocode

I'm trying to write pseudo code to solve the following problem:

Input: n teams in a basketball match. Each team Ti, Tj play and their win/loss record is in matrix A
(for i < j, A[i, j] = 1 if Ti beats Tj)

A team gets a medal if they don't lose more than 10 times.

Output: all teams that receive medals. Find in O(n) time.

This is my pseudo-code so far. Pseudo-code is enough for now but I don't think this works correctly nor does it run in linear time.

```
//input: matrix A of win/losses
//output: list of teams with medals
set S to an array of length n, with value 0 for all indices //keeps track of number of losses
for each team:
    for each game played in the team's row in M:
        if the team won:
            increment the opponent’s number of losses in the opponent’s index of S
        else:
            increment the team's number of losses in team's index of S
            if at any point a value in the array S reaches 11, remove that team from the list of teams we consider //so basically ignore all the games they play from hereon out
    end for loop
end for loop
take this new potential list of teams with medals
iterate through each team's row in M, counting losses       //to check if they lost against any of the teams we removed from the previous for loop
if losses > 10, remove the team from list
return final list
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a question / problem with this code

Comment: you can't find in O(n) time because, you need to iterate through the 2d array in order to get the count of losses right, so obviously worst case time complexity would be O(n^2).

Comment: You count every game twice like this, it's easier to only look at the 0s and ignore the 1s. Or do the inner loop only for each following team.

Comment: @zenwraight it's not necessary to iterate through the entire 2d array, because of the condition "A Team gets a medal if they don't lose more than 10 times". Once 11 losses were encountered for a team, it's fine to not further look in its row of the matrix.

Comment: @qwertyman good idea but again some base conditions like the 11 losses occur for a team in the last 11 columns only ... so in that case we would end up iterating till the end and so our worst case time complexity could go around O(n^2).

Comment: @zenwraight yes, this approach would not work, but I still feel that it is possible to do it in O(n) somehow (please also take a look at my answer to this question, if you are interested). The approach in my answer would work if _e.g._ we were interested in finding a team which didn't loose any match (which sounds simple, but is not possible in O(n) using an approach like the ones discussed in the previous comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on qwertyman's approach, we can solve this in `O(n)` as follows:

- Keep track of the number of losses for each team
- Keep track of the remaining teams (i.e. those with 10 or less losses - we do this by keeping an array of indices and swapping elements around for constant time removal)
- Loop over all possible match-ups from the remaining teams

  - Increase the loss count of the losing team
  - If that loss count is greater than 10, remove that team from the remaining teams
  - Note: This loop might appear to take `O(n²)`, but the number of remaining teams decreases fast enough for this to only take `O(n)`.
    You can see this from the fact that we increase a loss count ever iteration, and the maximum sum of loss counts is `11*n` (because once a loss count is 11, we remove it from consideration and don't increase it any more), thus this loop runs at most `11*n` = `O(n)` times.
- Now there will be at most 21 teams remaining.
  This is if we're not aware of any losses of a remaining team against any team already removed (it's easy to see that this is the best case), and then each remaining team won against 10 of the other 20 remaining teams. 22 teams is impossible, because each team will need to have won at least 11/21 games to maintain 10 or less losses, leading to more wins than losses, which is impossible considering that each game has 1 winner and 1 loser.
- For each remaining team, we simply run over all games for that team and count the number of losses (21 loops of `O(n)` = `O(n)`) and output the teams with 10 or less losses.

Java-like code: (slightly modified working version for readability)

```java
// returns true if i beat j or false if j beat i
boolean beat(int i, int j);
// return the loser in the game between i and j
int loser(int i, int j);
// swaps i with the last element in indices and decreases index count, takes O(1)
void removeIndex(int i);

// x = indices[y] corresponds to a remaining team x
int[] indices = new int[n];
// number of elements in indices, decreased in removeIndex
int indicesCount = n;
```

---

```java
// initialise our array of indices
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    indices[i] = i;

// initialise our array of losses
losses = new int[n];

// loop over all possible match-ups and eliminate (some) teams with > 10 losses
for (int a = 0; a < indicesCount; )
{
    for (int b = a+1; losses[indices[a]] <= 10 && b < indicesCount; )
    {
        losses[loser(indices[a], indices[b])]++;

        if (losses[indices[b]] > 10)
            removeIndex(b);
        else
            b++;
    }
    if (losses[indices[a]] > 10)
        removeIndex(a);
    else
        a++;
}

// find teams with <= 10 losses
for (int i = 0; i < indicesCount; i++)
{
    int lossCount = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        if (indices[i] == j)
            continue;
        else if (beat(j, indices[i]))
            lossCount++;
    if (lossCount <= 10)
        // output indices[i]
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/dFi37o).

Comment: This is a very nice solution, thanks for taking the time to explain it! I really like the double loop which actually takes O(n) -- that idea is something that I missed in my solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in O(n) is a very interesting question.

It might be possible, because we are only interested in the teams that don't lose more than 10 times.

But even with this constraint, finding an O(n) algorithm, and proving it's O(n), is not straightforward.

---

First, here is something that **does not work**: take each row of the matrix (representing one team), look at its elements one by one, and as soon as we encounter 11 losses, break the loop for this team, skipping the rest of its results.

This is still O(n^2) -- consider for example the case where lower indexed teams always lose against higher indexed teams. The results matrix will be lower triangular (below diagonal we will have only 1's, and above it only 0's).

In this case, the algorithm mentioned would need to investigate all elements below the diagonal (because they are all 1's, at the beginning of the rows, leading to no progress in reaching the 11 losses, where we break the loop). So at least (n^2 - n) / 2 elements are investigated here, thus this approach isn't in O(n).

The pseudo-code that you mentioned is a better attempt than this, but it's also not in O(n). This can be seen using the same counter-example. (In addition, the pseudo-code is not correct, because it sometimes double-counts losses, but this could be fixed by using an additional array which would indicate the last processed match of each team).

---

I'll describe now an idea that **seems to work**. This appears to be on the right track, but there are some complications which I couldn't solve yet.

In order to be in O(n) we need to carefully choose the matches at whose results we look at.

We will maintain 11 sets of teams: L0, L1, ..., L11.

- L0 is the set of teams for which we are currently not aware of any loss. Initially, all the teams are in this set.
- L1 is the set of teams for which we currently know they had 1 loss.
- ...
- L10 is the set of teams for which we currently know they had 10 losses.
- L11 is the set of teams for which we currently know they had more than 10 losses.

Initially, L0 will contain all teams, and the other sets will be empty.

Now, make pairs of the teams in L0. Investigate their matches, move the losers in L1. This will involve about n/2 operations, and we will be left with about n/2 teams in L0 and n/2 teams in L1 ("about n/2", because n might be odd, in which case one team will not be paired now).
Repeat the process for the n/2 teams left in L0, again move the losers in L1. This will require n/2/2 = n/4 operations.
Continue like this until only one team is left in L0. This will require a number of n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 operations, which is in O(n).

We are now left with only one candidate for the set L0, which is good enough (we can investigate in O(n) whether it indeed had below 10 losses).

Apparently we could continue like this and move towards L2 the teams which are now in L1, in O(n), then in L3, and so on, until most teams are pushed into L11 (where we don't care about them anymore). But pushing teams out of L1 is not as simple as for L0 -- we now need to be careful about which matches we look at, because some of them might have already been investigated in the previous stages.

Comment: Nice idea. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923941/1711796) for a working version.